# At what point in the ML pipeline should I under/over sample?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, unbalanced-classes, oversampling, under-sampling

I have an imbalanced multi-class dataset, and am under/over sampling to balance it out. My questions is when should I do this resampling? Should it occur before creating the test set, before creating a validation set or afterwards?

```
                        <--- (here: resampling of whole dataset)
split train/test
                        <--- (here: resampling of train and validation set)
split train/validation
                        <--- (or here: resampling of train set only)
```

Comment: See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/oversampling/info).

Comment: Thanks for this!

Comment: Just to be clear - undersampling is justified for computational efficiency.

Comment: @seanv507 I have quite a large dataset (>500,000 instances) so computational efficiency is slowly becoming an issue as the dataset grows. When should I perform this under sampling?